# Select only JPA Collection members meeting condition

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, jpql

I'm trying to select entries for Entity A where **all** of the children in its collection of CReference entities meet a condition.  The query I currently have only requires the conditions to be met on at least one of the members.

## Current Query

This query currently selects all objects of type A where at least one of the items in its c_references class

```
SELECT a FROM A a INNER JOIN FETCH a.c_references c_refs INNER JOIN FETCH c_refs.c_reference c_ref WHERE (c_ref.flag_one=TRUE AND c_ref.flag_two=TRUE)
```

## Classes

### Class A

```
@Entity
public class A{
```

```
@Id
private UUID a_uuid;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "owning_a_uuid")
private List<CReference> c_references;
```

}

### Class CReference

```
@Entity
// This class keeps references to all of the A objects that have referenced a C object
public class CReference{
```

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long c_reference_id;

@OneToOne
private A a_referencing_c;

@OneToOne
private C c_reference;
```

}

### Class C

```
@Entity
@Cacheable
public class C{
```

```
@Id
private UUID c_uuid;

private Boolean flag_one = false;

private Boolean flag_two = false;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a FROM A a 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(    
    SELECT c_refs
    FROM CReference c_refs
        INNER JOIN c.c_reference c_ref    
    WHERE
        c_refs.a_referencing_c = a
        AND (c_ref.flag_one = FALSE OR c_ref.flag_two = FALSE)
)
```